# iPhone 7 XCode 8 iOS 10, Tethered Build The Service is Invalid (0xE8000022)

Tags: iphone, ios10, xcode8

Current version of XCODE, iPHONE 7, IOS 10, trying to do a teathered build, setting the error

```
An error was encountered while attempting to communicate with this device. (The service is invalid).  Please try rebooting and reconnecting the device (oxE8000022).
```

We have tried ALL of the tricks, yes ALL of them and still getting the errror.  iPhone 6's, 5's, all work ok.

Both iPhone 7 and iPhone 7+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our case we had to factory reset the phone / software / ios and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

If device is jailbroken this error message displays in Xcode.